# How can I include a build number in the JAR file name?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project, which is built using Maven assembly plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have a file `BUILD.txt`, which contains the current build number.

When I call `mvn assembly:single`, I want `maven-assembly-plugin` to generate a JAR file (with all dependencies) called `myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.BUILD.jar`, where BUILD is the text from `BUILD.txt` (i. e. if `BUILD.txt` contains 172, the result JAR should be called `myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT.172.jar`).

How can I read the text from `BUILD.txt` such that I can use it in the `finalName` setting of the assembly plugin?

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.${build}.jar</finalName
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1

- Use [Maven Properties Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html)
- Change your `BUILD.txt` to contain `buildNumber=NNN`
- Use property `${buildNumber}` for `<finalName>`

### Approach 2

- *Assumption* You use an SCM like SVN or Git
- *No Need* to use `BUILD.txt` anymore
- Use [Maven Build Number Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)
- Use property `${buildNumber}` for `<finalName>`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.${build}.jar</finalName
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
</plugin>
```

With `appendAssemblyId` you will avoid the `jar-with-dependencies` suffix. You should generate the `BUILD.txt` as a properties files and then access to it as a normal properties file in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this :

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
```

put it in your pom (build section), then configure it to access your scm.
Then define your bundleFileName, e.g. like this

```
<bundleFileName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</bundleFileName>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question, which is reading the `BUILD.txt` file?

Comment: well, it really doesn't, however it answers the question "how can I include a build number in the jar file name?" which is the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the creation of this build file and can't change its content, a way to do that would be to read the file using an Ant task with [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), store the content inside a property and then use that property for the final name.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <!-- this task will read the content of the file and store it inside the "build" property -->
          <loadfile property="build" srcFile="BUILD.txt" />
        </target>
        <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties> <!-- Ant properties are not exported as Maven properties by default so we need to add it -->
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}.${build}.jar</finalName
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind the maven-assembly-plugin to the package phase instead -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running Maven with `mvn clean install` will generate the correct name for the assembly.

Note however that instead of doing this, you could use the `buildnumber-maven-plugin` which already deals automatically with build number, freeing you with the burden of maintaining a `BUILD.txt` file.